# Get stats from World Screen Resultion, in percentage greater than a value?

Tags: statistics, resolution, screen-resolution

I search statistics website where I can get the percentage of screen resolution **greater than/lower than** 1200px or 1024px width (in world).

The problem of statcounter.com is that they give resolution, but one by one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found some information on this topic.
Please, refer to the article by following link:http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_Display.asp